# Can I use feedkeys() inside of a keyloop implemented by getchar()

Tags: vimscript, search, cursor-movement, ex-mode

I implemented a fuzzy filter, which

- accept a list argument,
- open a window with a scratch buffer whose content set to the list, then
- waiting for use input and do filtering.

Here is why I ask this question, in the key loop, I want

- after `/` was type, go into a pass through mode, just like `/` was typed in normal mode, thus subsquent keys will do search, and move cursor of the scratch window, since `incsearch` was set,
- after `<C-c>` or `<C-m>` was typed, return back to previous key loop mode.

Is there any way to achieve above effect? I tried define a Handler for `/`, which `getchar()` then `feedkeys()` after `feedkeys('/')`, but seems caused infinite recursion/loop, which bumps cpu usage to 24%.

Comment: let me see if I've got this right: you create a scratch buffer with content. On `/`, you want to `feedkeys('/')` in order to search (so you probably did a mapping). `feedkeys()` takes a flag to not use mappings... but you could also consider using whatever other programs like `:FZF` or `Unite` is using these days

Comment: using `sleep` might help with the cpu

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ben Knoble, I do use plugins, ctrlp and LearderF, both used extensively actually. But non of the plugins around support behavior I wanted, thus I want implement it myself.

Comment: @Mass No, the problem is I was in a loop of getchar(), call feedkeys() there cause the arguments of feedkeys() feeded to the loop itself, thus resulting infinite loop.

Comment: What I want is inside of key loop that accept user input, to switch to search mode, to move cursor faster than press <up> <down>, its kinda like a key loop inside of key loop, or switch to normal mode, doing search, then restore previous key loop after search finished.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Actually, feedkeys() is just my failed trial, what I want is, say inside interactive filtering of `:Unite` or `:Ctrlp`, stop filtering temporarily, do search to move the cursor of the scratch window, after that, restore to previous interactive fitering, e.g., accept the cursor line immediately, or filter further.

Comment: I was suggesting you borrow their code, actually, but /shrug. Tbh it’s just not clear what the goal is.

Comment: Doing getchar(1) in loop is problematic https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/issues/605
I really suggest you to look at cli.py of leaderF for an implementation.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want, common fuzzy filter only list matching result, there is no need to use `/` in it, as all results are already filtered. If you want to turn on highlight, you can juset set the `/` register, turn on `hlsearch`, and posibbly a `redraw`. By the way there is a `CmdlineChanged` event.